# Bulk Insert of a txt file

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, bulkinsert

have a txt file and have to pass it to sql

When I run the command

```
insert into tb WITH (FIRE_TRIGGERS) (sField) 
select sField
FROM  OPENROWSET( BULK  'C:\import\file.txt',
          FORMATFILE ='C:\import\tbl.xml'
                )
    as t1
```

I get output error:
 **"FIRE_TRIGGERS" option is not recognized table hints.**

Anyone any ideas how I can achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

OPENROWSET BULK behaves differently to BULK INSERT. Its behaviour is closer to SELECT and INSERT and that is the operation you are actually performing above.

By default, INSERT applies triggers. 
There is a table hint to `IGNORE_TRIGGERS` to override this.

So just remove the `WITH (FIRE_TRIGGERS)` hint and the triggers should fire.

Russell